# Console calls (like cache clears or behat) throw an exception but all is fine in browser

Tags: php, symfony, assetic, behat

I am creating a Symfony2 application, all works well, but when i try to execute my behat tests or clear the cache, i got this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator::isFresh() in 
[...]/vendor/symfony/assetic-
bundle/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/Factory/Resource/FileResource.php line 49
```

TemplateLocator does not even implements LoaderInterface, as required in FileResource construct.
Anyone has a clue ?

Comment: have you compared your php.ini files (webserver and cli)?

Comment: Yes, I didn't saw any notable differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where the problem came from, but without understanding it.
It appeared that somewhere in my application I called

```
$this->container->get('twig')->render("Bundle:View:action.html.twig")
```

I changed to

```
$this->container->get('templating')->render("Bundle:View:action.html.twig")
```

twig service is a Twig_Environment instance, and template is a DelegatingEngine instance, both allowing to render a template.
And all works great again.
If someone could explain me what happened, I'll appreciate :)